# Can Pixelmator handle Photoshop layer styles?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, tools, pixelmator

Can Pixelmator handle Photoshop layer styles? How compatible is Pixelmator with the rest of Photoshop and the other Adobe graphics programs?

Comment: Good question. I just bought it the other day and am very impressed. For the price is seems incredibly robust. It does seem to handle PSD layers well, but not sure about the styles.

Comment: Linked: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4600/is-pixelmator-a-viable-alternative-for-photoshop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested it and the answer is, sadly, no. Pixelmator does not retain any of the effects used on layers within the original PSD file.

Bummer.